# storing grafana's metrics data in influxdb

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I use grafana(`3.0.3`) fetching cloudwatch data, and I want to store fetched data inside InfluxDB(`0.13`). Any idea how I can do so, thank you in advance.

Comment: One idea is to use `telegraf`, which reads `cloudwatch` then stores the data in `influxdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf) has a [CloudWatch](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/cloudwatch) plugin that you can use to store CloudWatch data in InfluxDB.

Alternatively if you're fetching the data yourself you could write the data to InfluxDB yourself. To do so, you'd issue an `POST` request to the `/write` endpoint of your InfluxDB instance with some your data in [line protocol](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/write_protocols/line/)

Some examples of data in line protocol:

```
cpu,host=server01,region=uswest value=1 1434055562000000000
cpu,host=server02,region=uswest value=3 1434055562000010000
temperature,machine=unit42,type=assembly internal=32,external=100 1434055562000000035
temperature,machine=unit143,type=assembly internal=22,external=130 1434055562005000035
```

Comment: thx a lot, just don't know why `grafana` drops the support for influxdb as a database backend for storing dashboard.

Comment: There were some issues in the past where people were losing their dashboards because of how it was store in InfluxDB.To prevent that from happening they started using SQL.